# Select2 shows native select next to the styled one on touch devices (iOS,...)

Tags: javascript, html, ios, touch, jquery-select2

When invoking the select2 dropdown the native Select is still visible. How can I prevent the site from displaying it?

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the native Selects by applying

```
select {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```